# How to seperate the values of a dictionary to space

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I have a dictionary, and I am using this code to print its first 3 key—value pairs.

```
[print(v) for i, v in enumerate(dict_data.items()) if i < 2]
```

```
Output:
(1, ['qd inc', 'san diego', '11578 sorrento valley road'])
(2, ['argon jg hannoosh', 'phil mag', 'initiation crazes polystyrene'])
```

I want to split the values of each key into the space, so my desired output is:

```
Desired Output: 

(1, ['qd', 'inc', 'san', 'diego', '11578', 'sorrento', 'valley', 'road'])
(2, ['argon', 'jg', 'hannoosh', 'phil', 'mag', 'initiation', 'crazes', 'polystyrene'])
```

I tried running this code but I get an error! (AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split')

```
dict_data = {key: [int(val) for val in value.split()] for key, value in dict_data.items()}
```

Comment: Can you include your dictionary code?

Comment: `int(val) for val in value.split()` this is confused ... `value` here is the list of items like  `['qd inc', 'san diego', '11578 sorrento valley road']` ... `for val in value` would give you each phrase in the list, so it's `val` you need to split on.  `int(val)` isn't going to do anything useful, to get the numeric index you need to use `enumerate` again like the original code

Comment: I am importing a csv file with more tha 60k entries as a dataframe which I clean and then i convert it to a dataframe. But I suppose that the code to create the above dictionary (with the first 2 entries) is the following

```
dict_data = {1 : ['qd inc', 'san diego', '11578 sorrento valley road'], 2 : ['argon jg hannoosh', 'phil mag', 'initiation crazes polystyrene']}
```

Comment: ...actually no, you don't need `enumerate` because the numbers are the keys of the original dict, so you can just use `key` var

Comment: your desired output is a list of tuples, as shown, or a new dictionary?

Comment: A new dictionary @Anentropic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
new_dict = {}
for key, value in dict_data.items():
    for phrase in value:
        new_dict.setdefault(key, []).extend(phrase.split())
```